# How to rotate a GameObject around another object according to the mouse cursor position in C#

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rotate an object based on mouse cursor movement(like bubble gun in bubble shooter game). But I'm Filed to do that with my script.

MY script is :

```
mouse_pos = Input.mousePosition;
Debug.Log(mouse_pos);
object_pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
mouse_pos.x = mouse_pos.x - object_pos.x;
mouse_pos.y = mouse_pos.y - object_pos.y;
angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouse_pos.y, mouse_pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,-angle);
```

It rotates only its same position it won't move.
Please any one help me to solve this. Or point me to any good tutorial ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then the object's transform is rotating around it's local origin, which is why you are seeing the correct rotation but no translation.

Unity applies transformations in the following order: scale, translate, rotate.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to parent your object's transform to another parent transform and rotate the parent transform instead (having applied a translation to your object's transform). Note that you will have to modify any scaling or translation on your object's transform because it will now be inheriting the parent transform's rotation.

Hope that helps, otherwise please provide more detail on your problem.